# Cant click on my link

Tags: html

i have a problem with my code. I try to make a connection between 2 files %.php but still not work. Can someone help me?:D here the code from index

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title.$sep.$description; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="frontend/design/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="frontend/design/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            Title
        </div>
        <div>
            <a herf="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What happens when you click on the link?

Comment: Nothing. I cant click the link. My coursor isn't a hand with a finger up. (Srry idk how to explain). My coursor is like when i wanna to copy/select something or when i try to write in a textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's spelled `href` not `herf`

`<a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a>`

Comment: Obviously you're not familiar with Herf.js, the trendy new Javascript MVC framework.  This is how page links are done..

Comment: OMG! I stay at this problem 30min +, i changed the sheetstyle and another things in index...but that i havent seen. Tnx guys and srry for that awkward questions :D

Answer (score 0):

Please check there is typo.

```
<a herf="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a>

should be <a href...
```

Comment: Ty! Apparent i'm blind